# Proof that $\mathbb{E}(|y_n|) <\infty$?

Tags: martingales, conditional-expectation

Let $\{x_n,\mathcal{F}_n,n\ge 1\}$ be a martingale differences sequence. Put $x_n'=x_n \mathbf{1}_{\{ |x_n|\le a_n \}}$ with $a_n\ge 0$ and $$y_n=x_1'+\cdots+x_n'-\mathbb{E} (x_2'\mid\mathcal{F}_1) - \cdots -\mathbb{E} (x_n'\mid\mathcal{F}_{n-1}). $$ I need to proof that $\mathbb{E}(|y_n|) <\infty$ for all $n\ge 1$. I proved it as follows:

Because $x'_i$ is independent with $\mathcal{F}_{i-1}$, $i\ge 2$ so
    \begin{align*}
  \mathbb{E} (|y_n|) &= \mathbb{E} \left[|x_1'+\cdots+x_n' - \mathbb{E} (x_2'\mid\mathcal{F}_1) -\cdots- \mathbb{E}(x_n'\mid\mathcal{F}_{n-1})| \right] \\
  & \le \mathbb{E} \left[ |x_1'+\cdots+x_n'| +\mathbb{E}( |x_2'|\ |\mathcal{F}_1) +\cdots+ \mathbb{E} (|x_n'| \ |\mathcal{F}_{n-1})\right] \\
  & =  \mathbb{E} (|x_1'+\cdots+x_n'|) +  \mathbb{E} (|x_2'|) +\cdots+ \mathbb{E} (|x_n'|) \\
  & \le  2\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E} (|x_i|) <\infty \text{ almost surely ,}\\
  & \ \ (\text{Since } \{ x_n \} \text{ is  a martingale differences sequence so } \mathbb{E} (|x_n|)<\infty ).
 \end{align*}
Is this wrong or right?

Comment: "Because $x'_i$ is indepe(n)dent (of) $\mathcal{F}_{i-1}$" No. Even $x_i$ itself is not necessarily independent of $\mathcal{F}_{i-1}$. (And this is quite unneeded to show that $y_n$ is integrable.)

Comment: Thank you. And about "Since $\{x_n\}$ is a martingale differences sequence so  $\mathbb{E} (|x_n|)<\infty$"? Is this necessary? is $\mathbb{E} (|y_n|)$ finite If we only have $ \mathbb{E} (x_n^+)<\infty$ or $\mathbb{E} (x_n^-)<\infty$ ?